# How to use global variables in .feature file in Cypress

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, cucumber, cypress

I have two questions about cypress/cucumber.

The first one is:
[image]
In which way can I use global variables in step definitions as parameters instead of giving strings ints etc?

The second one is I want to write my own methods to use whenever I want so that's why I tried to write some methods but I failed. (like in java/selenium)

I don't want to use Cypress.Command.add(). I want to write and call my methods as standard selenium methods which I call with their name and feed with parameters.

So my question is there another way to write my own reusable methods to use instead of Cypress.Command.add() command. if there is a way the anyone can show me one example about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class to store your functions and then just export them and import where you want to use them with -->

```js
const utils = require(path)
```

```js
class utils {
    getWorkOrderWithAttachment(index) {
        return incidents[index]
    }
}
module.exports = new utils()
```